# RadCalendar Nativescript+Angular doesn't translate allDayText

Tags: angular, calendar, nativescript, nativescript-angular

In a Nativescript+Angular application I'm using RadCalendar component with locale="it-IT":

```
 <RadCalendar [eventSource]="calendarEvents" id="calendar" #calendar 
    (navigatingToDateStarted)="onNavigatingToDateStarted($event)" 
    (loaded)="calendarLoaded($event)" locale="it-IT" eventsViewMode="Inline">
 </RadCalendar>
```

All works fine, the months are correctly translated. But when I open the inline events, if one of them fill all the day, it shows the label 'all day' in english:

[image]

I tried to format it manually, but it doesn't work:

```
calendarLoaded(args: EventData) {
    this.calendar.nativeElement.dayViewStyle.dayEventsViewStyle = new DayEventsViewStyle();
    this.calendar.nativeElement.dayViewStyle.dayEventsViewStyle.timeLabelFormat = "HH:mm";
    this.calendar.nativeElement.dayViewStyle.allDayEventsViewStyle = new AllDayEventsViewStyle();
    this.calendar.nativeElement.dayViewStyle.allDayEventsViewStyle.allDayText = "Intera giornata";
    this.calendar.nativeElement.reload();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Try this, `const allDayStyle = new AllDayEventsViewStyle(); allDayStyle.allDayText = "Intera giornata"; this.calendar.nativeElement.dayViewStyle.allDayEventsViewStyle = allDayStyle;`

Comment: @Manoj I got this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.calendar.nativeElement.dayViewStyle.allDayEventsViewStyle = allDayStyle')

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should be undefined. Can you share a Playground sample.